# How to properly print file content to the command line in C?

Tags: c, linux

I want to print the contents of a .txt file to the command line like this:

```
main() {
    int fd;
    char buffer[1000];
    fd = open("testfile.txt", O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    close(fd);
}
```

The file testfile.txt looks like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

The function prints only the first 4 letters `line`.
When using `sizeof` instead of `strlen` the whole file is printed.
Why is `strlen` not working?

Comment: What do you expect `strlen` to yield for an indeterminate buffer?

Comment: you should check the return values from your function calls too! especially in the case of the `read()` call as that tells you where you need to put the null-termination in your buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When using sizeof instead of strlen the whole file is printed. Why is
>   strlen not working?

Because how [strlen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strlen.html) works is it goes through the char array passed in and counts characters till it encounters 0. In your case, `buffer` is not initialized - hence it will try to access elements of uninitialized array (`buffer`) to look for 0, but reading uninitialized memory is not allowed in C. Actually you get undefined behavior.

`sizeof` works differently and returns the number of bytes of the passed object directly without looking for a 0 inside the array as `strlen` does.

As correctly noted in other answers read will not null terminate the string for you so you have to do it manually or declare `buffer` as:

```
char buffer[1000] = {0};
```

In this case printing such buffer using `%s` and `printf` after reading the file, will work, only assuming read didn't initialize full array with bytes of which none is 0.

*Extra*:

[Null terminating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) a string means you append a 0 to it somewhere. This is how most of the string related functions guess where the string ends.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works now when I add `buffer[strlen(buffer) + 1] = '\0';`

Comment: @sininen Uh, that's either undefined behavior or a no-op, depending on whether there is already a zero byte somewhere within the buffer.

Comment: @zwol So I should stick to using `sizeof`?

Comment: @shininen The correct third argument to `read` is indeed `sizeof buffer`.  Use of `printf("%s\n", buffer)` is _also_ wrong.

Comment: Initializing as suggested with `char buffer[1000] = {0}; ... read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer); printf("%s\n", buffer);` is not so great either as `printf("%s\n", buffer);` may attempt to print an array of 1000 characters without a null character.  Better to read up to 1 less the buffer size and use the return value from `read()` to know where to append the `'\0'`.

Comment: @chux  The case you are referring to I have already addressed in my answer, isn't it? (text after the code.)

Comment: "null terminate the string for you so you have to do it manually or _declare buffer as_: `char buffer[1000] = {0};"` is the problem.  After the `read(fd, buffer...` call, the entire array may lack a null character.  The double negative of "assuming read didn't initialize full array with bytes of which none is 0." and its use of _initialize_ (its assigning, `buffer[1000] = {0}` is initializing)  lacks clarity.  I see your point there only after a few re-reads.

Answer (score 6):

It is incorrect to use `strlen` *at all* in this program.  Before the call to `read`, the buffer is uninitialized and applying `strlen` to it has undefined behavior.  After the call to `read`, some number of bytes of the buffer are initialized, but *the buffer is not necessarily a proper C string*; `strlen(buffer)` may return a number having no relationship to the amount of data you should print out, or may still have UB (if `read` initialized the full length of the array with non-nul bytes, `strlen` will walk off the end).  For the same reason, `printf("%s\n", buffer)` is wrong.

Your program also can't handle files larger than the buffer at all.

The right way to do this is by using the return value of `read`, and `write`, in a loop.  To tell `read` how big the buffer is, you use `sizeof`.  (Note: if you had allocated the buffer with `malloc` rather than as a local variable, then you could *not* use `sizeof` to get its size; you would have to remember the size yourself.)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buf[1024];
    ssize_t n;
    while ((n = read(0, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0)
        write(1, buf, n);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("read");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Exercise: cope with short writes and write errors.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is strlen not working?

Because when you call it in `read(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));`, you haven't yet assigned a *valid* string to `buffer`.  It contains some indeterminate data which may or may not have a 0-valued element.  Based on the behavior you report, `buffer` just so happens to have a 0 at element 4, but that's not reliable.

The third parameter tells `read` how many bytes to read from the file descriptor - if you want to read as many bytes as `buffer` is sized to hold, use `sizeof buffer`.  `read` will return the number of bytes read from `fd` (0 for `EOF`, -1 for an error).  IINM, `read` will *not* zero-terminate the input, so using `strlen` on `buffer` after calling `read` would *still* be an error.